# a dynamic link library (dll) initialization routine failed when build electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, electron, initialization

error that when i run builded electron program

[image: 1]

the program operate well in my computer but,when i build by 'electron-builder --win portable' and move to other computer then the error occured. (coding in window 11, test in window 10)
how do i fix it?

package.json

```
    "scripts": {
        "build:renderer": "webpack --config ./client/webpack.config.renderer.js",
        "build:main": "tsc --project ./client/tsconfig.json",
        "build": "npm run build:main && npm run build:renderer",
        "build:addon:x86": "(cmake-js -G \"Visual Studio 16 2019\" -A Win32 -O build_Win32)",
        "build:addon:x64": "(cmake-js -G \"Visual Studio 16 2019\" -A x64 -O build_x64)",
        "start": "electron . --enable-logging",
        "copy_binary": "copy_binary.bat",
        "dist": "electron-builder --win portable"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "cmake-js": "^7.0.0",
        "electron-rebuild": "^3.2.7",
        "ts-loader": "^9.4.1",
        "typescript": "^3.1.0",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "electron": "16.0.10",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "node-addon-api": "^4.1.0"
    },
    "cmake-js": {
        "runtime": "electron",
        "runtimeVersion": "16.0.10"
      }
```

i tried that...

1. add "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps" in package.json
2. add set(DELAY_LOAD_HOOK "hook/win_delay_load_hook.cc") in cmakelists.txt

Comment: Same here with governlay library, I tried a lot of things, nothing worked so far

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it copying the old [binding.gyp](https://github.com/hiitiger/goverlay/blob/5c0266879c5464911185d2a37a5f9be9881767eb/electron-overlay/binding.gyp) file and ran electron-rebuild, the new .node file will be here .\electron-overlay\bin\win32-x64-109